# Converting a For Loops to Linq

Tags: linq

The below code is working as expected but I'm wondering is there a way to improve my code using Linq?

what I am doing is finding to see if the rows[5] and rows[6] has value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nameList.Count; i++)
{
     IList<IWebElement> rows = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("itd_1"));
     for (int k = 0; k < rows.Count; k++)
     {
        if (rows[5].Text != " " && rows[6].Text != " ")
        {
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rows[5].Text) || 
               !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rows[5].Text) && 
               !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rows[6].Text) || 
               !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rows[6].Text))
           {
              //do something here...
           }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: The outer loop seems to not be doing anything with the data?  You are just doing this `nameList.Count` times?  Seems like something is missing... do you mean to get the selector by `i`?  `"itd_" + i` perhaps?  In fact, your inner loop (`k`) isn't doing anything constructive either.  I think the example is broken.  We can't help you if the code is nonsensical.

Comment: What's the `for` loop for when you don't use `k` and access `rows` by index directly?

Comment: Your code is pretty weird. You do not use `i` nor `k` anywhere

Comment: the first for loop is the big list of 100 rows and the second for loop which is the count of 11 and since i know what item data i need thats why you see there hard coded value 5 and 6.... my code may not make sense but its working as suppose to be... those of you know Selenium API can understand what i am trying to do.

Comment: @thedailwtf: the reason i post is here to convert to linq, did you get it?

Comment: You should post correct code at the first place.

Comment: After reaching a point where your program works, you should remove code as long as it still works, to find out what actually made it work, and what code is unnecessary. Almost seems like a case of [programming by accident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation)

Comment: It's "possible" that he is using i and k inside the `//do something here` and he's changing the contents of `driver` inside there as well, so it wouldn't be useless code, just oddly coded.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = rows.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(x[5]) && !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(x[6]));
```

That's gonna get you an `IEnumerable` of the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the above

```
   rows.Where(x => x[5].Text != " " && x[6].Text  != " ")
            .Where(x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x[5].Text ) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x[5].Text )
                && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x[6].Text ) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x[6].Text ));
```

Comment: newStackExchangeInstance  You are right!! It was a rapid solution :)

Comment: All of those checks are irrelevant except the IsNullOrWhitespace ones.

Comment: string.Trim().IsNullOrEmpty() = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(), agree with newSEI

Answer (score 0):

This will do exactly what you had above, only with the redundant parts removed. Assuming the `//do something here..` block isn't changing the row values.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nameList.Count; i++)
{
     IList<IWebElement> rows = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("itd_1"));
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rows[5]) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rows[6]))
     {
        for (int k = 0; k < rows.Count; k++)
        {
              //do something here...
        }
    }
}
```